# Remove background colour of a PNG file in CSS

Tags: css

How to remove the background color of a png using CSS?

I am working on a website where I need to stack a png icon over a background image. Since the image is from an external API, I cannot edit it, beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

**Blend Modes**

So whilst browser support for these is pretty low, if you don't need to worry about IE/Edge/Mobile browsers this should be fine.

Pretty simple to use, what you'd want to do is apply your **background-image** and a **background-color** followed by your specified **background-blend-mode**

Whilst none will give you a perfect background change like that in image editing software, you'll get pretty close with ***multiply***.

Eg:

```
background-image: url('yourimage.png');
background-color: blue;
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Pure CSS [Limited Support]

The only way to do this is to use `mix-blend-mode` or `background-blend-mode` but unfortunately **it is not supported in IE and Edge** (check the support level [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)) If you need IE support see option 2.

You can read more about this CSS property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). By putting the blend mode to `screen` you can remove the white background of your png image.

```
  background-image: url(face.jpg);
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

## Option 2: ImageMagick [Need Backend]

You can create your own backend endpoint that fetches the image from the API, remove the background using ImageMagick and return the new transparent image. If the Icon is small you can even embed the image into the API as encode base64. Base65 encoding and decoding has [full](http://caniuse.com/#search=base64) browser support.